# Summing tensor over differing number of rows per column

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to be able to perform a reduce sum over a tensor in Tensorflow where for each column, we only sum over a subset of the rows. To illustrate, consider the following

```
import tensorflow as tf


X = tf.constant(
    [
        [1, 3, 2],
        [0, 5, 8],
        [1, 6, 2]
    ],
    tf.float32
)

row_max = tf.constant([3, 2, 1], tf.int64)
```

Then I want to do the following in Tensorflow so that gradients can flow:

```
partial_sum = 0.0

for col_idx in range(X.shape[1]):
    partial_sum += tf.reduce_sum(X[:row_max[col_idx], col_idx]])
```

This should give me `1+0+1+3+5+2 = 12`

I don't however know how to do this in Tensorflow. I've looked into a number of different methods, `tf.ragged.range`, `tf.segment_sum` etc. I think `tf.gather_nd` could work but even then I'm not sure how to build the index tensor. In Numpy I could do something like:

```
import numpy as np


X_np = X.numpy()

idx0 = np.concatenate(
    [
        i * np.ones(row_max[i])
        for i in range X_np.shape[1]
    ],
    axis=0
).astype(np.int64)

idx1 = np.concatenate(
    [
        np.arange(row_max[i])
        for i in range X_np.shape[1]
    ],
    axis=0
).astype(np.int64)


X_np[idx0, idx1].sum()
```

What is the best way to accomplish my goal in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do that:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(
    [
        [1, 3, 2],
        [0, 5, 8],
        [1, 6, 2]
    ],
    tf.float32
)
row_max = tf.constant([3, 2, 1], tf.int64)

# Make mask for each column
row_idx = tf.range(tf.shape(x, out_type=row_max.dtype)[0])
mask = tf.expand_dims(row_idx, 1) < row_max
mask_f = tf.dtypes.cast(mask, x.dtype)
# Mask elements and sum
result = tf.reduce_sum(mask_f * x)
tf.print(result)
# 12

# Alternatively, you can mask the elements and sum
result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.boolean_mask(x, mask))
```

Comment: Great! Any reason not to save a line of code, ignore the cast and do `result = tf.reduce_sum(x[mask])`. It also avoids any potential undefined values when you perform `mask * x` (although acknowledge this wasn't mentioned in the question).

Comment: You cannot do `tf.reduce_sum(x[mask])` in TensorFlow, but if you skip the `tf.dtypes.cast` operation you can do `tf.reduce_sum(tf.boolean_mask(x, mask))`.